# What are the Dinosaurs for on Wake Island?

Tags: battlefield-3

There are 5 or 6 dinosaurs 'lost' on Wake Island in the latest Battlefield 3 DLC. What are they there for, or what do they trigger once you find them?

Comment: Where are these dinosaurs on Wake Island?  I've played it a bunch and not noticed them.

Comment: I found this YouTube video detailing the Dinosaur locations. http://youtu.be/rUhrQyf-kec

Answer (score 18, accepted):

They're an easter egg put in the game due to a meme that spread around the internet originating on 4chan because of a lack of dinosaurs in Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 2.

[image: If the few curse words in this image are not allowed just let me know and I'll edit them out and repost this]

Basically when Battlefield 3 was announced, everyone was asking if there'd be a dinosaur mode.

Since they weren't actually putting a dinosaur mode in (or maybe they will in the future :P) they left lots of dinosaur related easter eggs around, one of them being the dinosaurs on Wake Island, another being the Dinosaur Dogtags and a third being this wallpaper that they circulated:

[image: Dino Wallpaper]